# Better Algorithm for finding two elements in an array that sums up to the provided value

Tags: javascript

I am writing an algorithm for finding two elements in an array that sums up to the provided value. i.e for array `[2, 7, 5, 3, 4, 11, 12, 56]` and value `9` I am finding two elements for eg. `2` and `7` which adds to our provided value `9`. I am getting the final result as `[ [ 2, 7 ], [ 4, 5 ] ]`. Please find the code below

```
const getSumOfValuesInArr = (arr, val) => {
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] + arr[i] === val) {
        result.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
    }
    }
}
console.log(result);
return result;
};

getSumOfValuesInArr([2, 7, 5, 3, 4, 11, 12, 56], 9);
```

But as you can it is a bit expensive. How can I write a better algorithm for better performance? Please help.

Comment: Your code as written does nothing like what you describe; you're adding the array **indexes** instead of the array values.

Comment: Hi @Pointy, yes you are correct. Thanks for pointing out. I will change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a single loop and store seen values in a hash table.

Then check if the delta of the wanted sum and the actual value is seen before then add the pair to the result set.

```js
const getSumOfValuesInArr = (arr, val) => {
    var result = [],
        seen = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (seen[val - arr[i]]) result.push([val - arr[i], arr[i]]);
        seen[arr[i]] = true;
    }

    return result;
};

console.log(getSumOfValuesInArr([2, 7, 5, 3, 4, 11, 12, 56], 9));
```